# Browsing multiple lists to find equal objects

Tags: java, list, duplicates

I want to know if 2 bus lines are crossing (have common busStop), and then return those lines and bus stop in a list.
**The `busLine` Class does not have method that returns the list of stops to use list operations**

For example: Im on 1st element of busLineList -> I get 1st busStop of the line -> now checking every other `busLineList` elements if it consist of the same busStop on it's list.

```
busLineList -> busLine 1 -> busStop A
                            busStop B

            -> busLine 2 -> busStop B


saving to the list: [ busLine 1, busLine 2, busStop B ]
```

My implementation returning wrong Lists. **The `size()` of returned list is a sum of every bus stop i use in all the bus lines.** 
**There is a problem with `if()` statement because when I replaced the condition with `true` it produced the same output.**

```
/* This list consist of `BusLineInterface` objects which constructor 
   takes a `List` of `BusStopInterface` objects as parameter.
*/
private static List<BusLineInterface> busLineList;

/* This is `transferList` I want to create which contains `Lists`
   of objects: bus x of line "x" that have same busStop with bus y on 
   line y, bus y, common bus stop
*/
private static List<List<Object>> transferList;

public PathFinder() {

    busList = new ArrayList<>();
    busLineList = new ArrayList<>();
    transferList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void transferTab() {

    for (int i = 0; i < busLineList.size(); i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < busLineList.get(i).getNumberOfBusStops(); j++) {

            for (int k = 0; k < busLineList.size(); k++) {
                boolean flag = true;
                if (i == k) { // Avoiding of checking same Lines
                    flag = false;
                }
                if (flag) {

                    for (int l = 0; l < busLineList.get(k).getNumberOfBusStops(); l++) {

                        if (busLineList.get(i).getBusStop(j).getName().equals(busLineList.get(k).getBusStop(l).getName())) {
                            List<Object> transfer = new ArrayList<>();

                            transfer.add(busLineList.get(i));
                            transfer.add(busLineList.get(k));
                            transfer.add(busLineList.get(k).getBusStop(l));
                            transferList.add(transfer);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: adding busLine and busStop methods

```
private String name;

BusStop(String n) {

    this.name = n;
}

@Override
public String getName() {

    return name;
}
```

Bus line:

```
private static List<BusStop> busStore;

BusLine(List<BusStop> b) {

    busStore = new ArrayList<>(b);
}

@Override
public int getNumberOfBusStops() {

    return busStore.size();
}
@Override
public BusStopInterface getBusStop(int number) {

    return busStore.get(number);
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use contains method the list?                                                                                         
     contains(Object o) -> It returns the boolean value

Comment: @Shivaraj I cant use `contains` here, bacause I don't have method in busLine that returning its busStops list, I can only use `getNumberOfBusStops` and `getBusStop' and unfortunately I can't edit this class to return whole list, but I know it would be much easier then

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are describing an intersection between two lists.

This will work:

```
List<String> list1 = ...
List<String> list2 = ...

Set<String> intersection = list1.stream()
                               .filter(item -> list2.contains(item))
                               .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: The problem is I cannot use `.contains' on busLine because that class doesn't have method returning the list given in constructor. It only consist of getters for amount of bus stops and for concrete bus stop so I need to manually iterate over the every bus stop, and I cannot add this method(which returning list), but I know it would be easier then.

Comment: perhaps you can share the BusInterface and BusLineInteface code.

Comment: I've just did it :)

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question.  What are you trying to do? (in the context of buses, bus lines, and bus stops.).  Something like...I want to find out if the same busstop is serviced by two different bus lines.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I edited the question again. I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is the same.  Internally '.contains' uses '.equals' for checking if the item is already in the list.  If this doesn't suffice, use the getName() method for comparing one stop to another by name. As follows:

```
    // Convert the list of bus stops to a set of names.
    Set<String> line1Stops = busLine1.stream()
                                 .map(stop -> stop.getName())
                                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    // Create an intersection set by comparing the names in
    // list 1 against the names in list 2.
    Set<String> intersection = busLine2.stream()
                                 .map(stop -> stop.getName())
                                 .filter(name -> line1Stops.contains(name))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: I don't know how to make it work, because `busLine1.stream()` assumes this is a `List` but it is an object which parameter is a `List` and I cant retrieve it (I must manually iterate over every bus stop)

Comment: Can you use iteration to build a list for each bus line?  Then do the evaluation of each list.